# In Asp Net Core, Do I have to put the Attribute of [Authorize] for both Get and Post Method?

Tags: asp.net-core, security

In the controller, normally we have a Get and a Post methods
for example:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Policy = "AdminMs")]
public async Task<IActionResult> MSCreate()
{
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(Policy = "AdminMs")]
public async Task<IActionResult> MSCreate(empolyee)
{
}
```

Do I have to set the  Authorize Attribute for both methods or only for HttpGet?

Comment: Yes and you could put it only on the controller if all actions inside the controller need to be authorized.

Comment: I thought that attribute `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` in combination with Authorize attribute in **HttpGet** would be sufficient security, and there is no need to add another authorize on **HttpPost**.

Comment: A user could use a program like Postman to execute a POST without ever needing to go to the page (and thus authorizing in the HttpGet). The AntiForgeryToken is a security against or XSRF/CSRF attacks: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-5.0) but Authorize should be on all actions (Get, Post, Put, Delete ...) that you want to protect.

Comment: This attribute is useful when you want to use the Authorize attribute on the controller to protect all operations in

Answer (score 1):

If you need only authorized access to any of the end points, you have to use `[Authorize]` on whichever method that corresponds to that endpoint. Having it on one method does not mean that it will restrict the other method even if they have similar method names.